# MonoDevelop not showing dll methods

Tags: c#, dll, mono

I have two projects made with Mono, I created a c# class library like this

```
Namespace TestSpace
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public TestClass()
        {
            System.Guid guid = System.Guid.NewGuid ();
            Id = guid.ToString ();
        }

        public void test()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I then compiled it and imported the dll to my other project and tried to use it like this

```
using TestSpace;

NameSpace Project
{
    public class Main
    {
        TestClass tc = new TestClass();

        public Main()
        {
            tc.Name = "test";
        }
    }
}
```

this works fine and I don't get any error but what's weird is that when I type "tc." it doesn't show any public variable or method available for auto-completion.
Now I'm fairly new with dlls I don't know if that's normal and I'm just not using it properly but when I tried to do the same thing in Visual Studio it showed all the public methods and variables.

So my question is if that's normal and I shouldn't use dlls like this (I'm just trying to code this way to reuse them in later projects) or if it's a bug in Mono or a bug that only I'm getting.

I'm using Mono-develop v3.0.3.2 on Ubuntu 12.10

thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know if this applies to you, but try looking at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885832/missing-intellisense-while-describing-custom-control-properties-declaratively)

Comment: You're using the DLL correctly, and you should see auto-completion. Does it help if you clean the project, exit monodevelop, and remove/re-add the reference? I've had auto-complete not show up before, but it's always come back with those steps.

Comment: I have tried to clean and rebuild both projects, exit and remove/readd the reference. It only shows the Equals, getHashCode, getType and ToString methods. But none of my own methods or variables

Comment: I'm rolling back your last edit. Posting the solution as an edit to the question isn't the way Stackoverflow works. If you've solved this yourself, you should post an answer. It's acceptable to answer your own question here, and you can even accept it as the correct solution after a period of time. The [faq] has more info about that to explain. You should provide the answer properly so it can benefit others in the future, and so it's clear you've found an answer to the problem.