# Unity MonoDevelop: Auto-complete's completely gone

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I've run into the same problem as this guy [on the Unity forums](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/121469/monodevelop-not-showing-autocomplete-intellisense.html), which already has its own [copy of the answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885832/missing-intellisense-while-describing-custom-control-properties-declaratively).

Except, these answers are out-of-date.

---

So, running on the newer MonoDevelop 4.0.1 (compared to 2.4.2), I've tried the solution that was given;

> Close MonoDevelop and delete the %AppData%\MonoDevelop-Unity\CodeCompletionData. After, reopen and MonoDevelop will regenerate all the configuration files and everything should be working fine again.

Except, the problem has gone from bad to worse:
MonoDevelop now does not list anything for auto-completion, from previously, only listing key methods/functions/whatevers (ie. `void`, `public`, `If` and not `rigidBody`, `fMath` etc.)
*It means "an empty auto-complete box" saying: "No autocompletions found.".*

**UPDATE:** It somewhat comes and go. One moment, auto-complete works fine, the next moment (without closing anything), it displays nothing.

**UPDATE:** I'm on PC, not Mac (Apple)!

**UPDATE:** As [@Thom Denick](http://answers.unity3d.com/users/3032/smorpheus.html) (Not an SO user) pointed out - Tried various solutions found around the Unity answers website. None worked, since they were mainly about Mac issues (even repeating steps given in Windows did nothing). | [Link 1](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/416662/mono-develop-lost-autocompletion-and-refactoring.html) [Link 2](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/560567/no-autocompletion-in-monodevelop.html) [Link 3](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/833989/monodevelop-suggestions-without-autocomplete.html).

Comment: Are you working on Mac OS X?

Comment: @Perumal93, I'm running on PC; Windows 8.

Comment: Go to Preferences -> External Tools -> Select Browse... under External Script Editor -> Navigate to Unity project folder -> in the folder navigate to MonoDevelop -> Select the file -> Click Open button -> Close the Preference window. Now check out if the Auto Code Completion works.

Comment: Um.. That option only comes up with "MonoDevelop (built-in)" and "Browse..." | Based on what you said, I simply clicked "Browse..." and selected the MonoDevelop executable.

Comment: EDIT: It's not working. The auto-complete still displays nothing other than *"No completions found"*.

Comment: Unity MonoDevelop is so outdated and broken.. If you are using Windows why don't you use VisualStudio 2013 Community Edition(or restrictions prohibit you)?

Comment: Otherwise, delete all the files like .sln and some other files in root directory of the Unity project you are currently working on. But, don't delete the folders like assets and whatever the folders that exist on root directory of the project. Now, sync your project in Unity.

Comment: Er.. @Perumal93 There are no `.sln` files to be found.

Comment: Maybe that's the reason for the issue.

Comment: @Perumal93 Except it's not generating new ones.

Comment: Check out these links. http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/416662/mono-develop-lost-autocompletion-and-refactoring.html. http://captain-andy.com/post/68043774987/fixing-monodevelop-autocompletion-in-unity3d-4-3.

Comment: @Perumal93, that's my [Link 1](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/416662/mono-develop-lost-autocompletion-and-refactoring.html) just repeated twice. I've already tried those solutions.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried
Opening  "MonoDevelop"
Clicking  "Tools"
Clicking  "Options"
Selecting  "General" under "Text Editor"
checking "Enable code completion"

Comment: Of course it's enabled, and also by default. The AutoComplete box appears, but there's nothing in it!

Comment: sorry that didn't help i did a bit of surfing and came across this http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/575280/unity-43-and-monodevelop-401-code-completion-gone.html  and http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/416662/mono-develop-lost-autocompletion-and-refactoring.html  .  maybe that will help. anyhow best of luck with your dilemma hope you solve it id hate to have no intellisence

Answer (score 0):

I am on a mac. But my school has had these problems before. The way that it was fixed for us was opening the monodevelop before you open unity. Hope this helps.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10370722)

Comment: Yes it does the way to fix this problem is to open monodevelop before you open unity.

Comment: Windows (PC) **not** Mac.

Comment: I know I am on a mac but my school works on pc's and that is how they fixed it.